# Testing service classes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I was wondering how you guys would test a Service Object class in Rails? Let's say a User signs up. A user is created in the database, is added to the email list, and other stuff happens. How do you test this?

```
class UserRegistrar
  def sign_up(user)
    User.create(user) # or something to this effect
    EmailMarketing.add_to_email_list(user)
    SuperSecretClass.do_secret_stuff(user)
    LoggingThing.new.log_stuff_about(user)
  end
end
```

(Controller action)

```
def create
    UserRegistrar.sign_up(params)
    # stuff for the strong params, etc...
end
```

What I do is to just make sure that the methods are called, with the correct arguments. The results of the methods (like making sure that a user is really added to the list) are tested in their respective classes. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if I needed to write a unit test for a class like the one you show, I'd do it the way you say, with mocks. In your example, all of the work is delegated to high-level model methods which will need their own tests and might be used in more than one place, so it doesn't make sense to test the functionality of those methods in tests of the service. And there are not that many method calls to mock, so it won't be too painful.

However,

- if any of those model methods were used only in one service, I'd consider moving those to the service to slim down the model and make the service more coherent. If I ended up with methods on the service that did a lot of work themselves, rather than just delegating, I'd test their functionality in tests of the service, by creating database objects and asserting how the service changes them.
- on the other hand, if I had a service that only delegated, it might already be fully tested by my acceptance test (since I'm doing BDD and write acceptance tests first), and there would be no need to unit-test the service at all.

Comment: I agree with the second point. In fact I am thinking of just doing the acceptance test as opposed to "must call the methods" (did a User get created, did the user get added to the mailing list). The "did I call this method" seems to not have much value (checking if something was called as to checking if something was changed).

Comment: Right, method call expectations have no intrinsic value; they're just stand-ins for testing state changes that are impractical to test.

Answer (score 1):

There's a danger to stubbing everything in your test, because then you're only testing that the class fits the test, instead of fitting in with the rest of your code. If `EmailMarketing.add_to_email_list` one day becomes `EmailMarketing.add_to(:email_list ...)` in a refactoring, your test wouldn't pick it up.

You can test the effects of the code like this, using `User` as an example:

```
expect {
  UserRegistrar.sign_up(user)
}.to change{
  user.persisted?
}.from(false).to(true)
```

Comment: Hmm now that you say that the class does seem coupled to the test. But aren't classes coupled to the test? How would you test such a class?

Comment: I would test the end results of the method, whether a user has been saved, added to the email list, secrets published, logs recorded etc... The goal is to make the test fail whenever the actual requirements are not met.